# Why is my button displayed but not clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've created a ViewController containing a user button, which is going to be present in several View Controllers in my application.
I'm adding this ViewController dynamically to the needed ViewControllers. The user button is shown, but it's not clickable. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried setting constraints to the view containing the button, setting the container view's frame, disabling user interaction in the container view (not in the button) and nothing seems to work

```swift
import UIKit

class ModulePageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addSharedButtonsSubView()
    }

    func addSharedButtonsSubView() {
        let sharedButtons = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: sharedButtonsViewControllerName)
        view.addSubview((sharedButtons?.view)!)
        sharedButtons?.view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.minX, y: view.frame.minY, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        addChild(sharedButtons!)
        sharedButtons?.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: we may need the code of `SharedButtonsViewController`, it seems you instanciate it from xib so the problem may be in this class. BTW can you be more precise on "not clickable" considering we cannot see any associated action in your code, what do you mean exactly by that

Comment: Plus it seems a bit messy. Why do you instanciate a ViewController, to extract its `view` then to add the VC itself `addChild(sharedButtons!)`. Here is a good tut that could help you to start all over again and figure out whats wrong: (DONT pay attention to the url, its not a troll...) https://medium.com/@how_noobs_think/how-to-instantiate-a-view-from-a-xib-file-f6034c282f7c

Comment: @Olympiloutre thank you for the attention! What I mean by "not clickable"  is that the button looks as it should, but when clicking on it, there's no animation nor event. The SharedButtonsViewController doesn't contain any custom code (yet), so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Olympiloutre thank you for the tutorial, I'll certainly look at it and see if there's a better way of achieving my goal.

Comment: Actually I really think you should start with it. By following the good practices itll be easier for you to spot mistakes, and for us to help you understand your code and debug it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view (not ViewController) containing the button and just use it where you need in you app.

Answer (score 0):

@LeCalore ...

I would recommend if you want to use a button or any more stuff on multiple View Controllers then you should just make a new ViewController with that button and whatever else you want on it then use it where ever you want.

ViewController -> Present As Pop Over  (Presentation : Over Current Context)

I think that's a better approach atleast for starters.

Else, as user said ... you can make a custom view programatically and call it wherever you need that's another approach but it might give you a bit of trouble. 
Open to others view if there's one better.
Gluck